# Hide "load more" button after the last item has been loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hide the "load more" button once the last 3 items are loaded on the site. I did it with the next and prev buttons and it works perfectly, but it doesn't work on the "load more" button. I think it's because of the default value, but how do I force it hide?

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Pagination({ goToNextPage, showMoreItems, goToPreviousPage }) {
  return (
    <div className="job-card-buttons">
      {goToPreviousPage && <button onClick={goToPreviousPage} >Back</button>}
      {showMoreItems && <button onClick={showMoreItems} >Load More</button>}
      {goToNextPage && <button onClick={goToNextPage ? goToNextPage : null} >Next</button>}
    </div> 
  )
}

const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState()
const [previousPage, setpreviousPage] = useState()
const [currentPageUrl, setCurrentPageUrl] = useState("list/")
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(3)

const showMoreItems = () => {
  setVisible(prevValue => prevValue + 3);
}
const goToNextPage = () => {
  setCurrentPageUrl(nextPage)
}

const goToPreviousPage = () => {
  setCurrentPageUrl(previousPage)
}
```

I use this in my JSX this way:

```
  <Pagination
  goToNextPage={nextPage ? goToNextPage : null}
  showMoreItems={visible ? showMoreItems : null}
  goToPreviousPage={previousPage ? goToPreviousPage : null}
  />
```

Comment: You need to show us the JSX for Load more. Then only community will be able to help.

Comment: Please make your code clearer. Why do you have all those lines after your `Pagination` component to do with state?

Comment: @Mike since I want to remove each buttons once there is no more data on it

Comment: Those lines need to be inside one of your components. I'm assuming they belong in Pagination's parent component since you're passing those functions to Pagination

Comment: @Mike yeah exactly, but even on parent dont work

Comment: "once the last 3 items were loaded on the site" This is a tricky line. Do you get the list of items and do you know the last item number? Based on that logic to setVisible can be changed. Also i feel setVisible should be a boolean not a number.

Comment: each dataset contains 100 elements per page, but how do I check the last page and remove load more button ? @SachinVishwakarma

Comment: Your Pagination component looks like it should be working. If null is passed as one of the functions, the buttons shouldn't be rendered. When in doubt, console.log is your friend. Find out what the variables contain, and if they don't contain what you think they do, find out why.

Comment: what is the last page that will be determined by API response only. Is API returning total number of elements or total number of pages? This information will be required to hide the load more button.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma the returns the 100 elements with dynamical number of pages, and each page contains 100 elements no matter what

Comment: can you explain why have you written this setVisible(prevValue => prevValue + 3); So far with my experience with pagination. you need to know the total number or records and records per page.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma it loads 3 elements at a time , and everything is back ended . the reactjs is just a nice shirt for our backend

Comment: ok, Thanks. Also my apologies if I am not able to understand the requirement. I will try to explain what I have understood so far. There is a list which has 100 items in it. you have started to show the pagination in the bottom of the list which has page numbers 1 2 3.. [LoadMore] like this. Now you want to hide load more button when user is on 4th page? is this correct or can you explain requirement from start?

Comment: exactly where `setVisible(prevValue => prevValue + 3);`  increments the value of `visible` until 99 which is the last element

Comment: In the above code variable `visible` is always incremented, so the `visible? showMoreItems: null` will always return `showMoreItems` hence the button will be displayed. 
You need to provide more code to help you